# Access NSUserdefault from a different ViewControl

Tags: xcode, nsuserdefaults

How can I access a NSUuserdefault from a different ViewControl than the one that I created it in?

I have tried creating another string and using that to make another NSUserdefault.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is accessible from everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!
I just need to call it like normal.